# Unable to install python3-tk in my ubuntu machine 16.04

Tags: python, ubuntu, tkinter

I am trying to make a very first desktop application using tkinter in pycharm like this.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
mLabel = Label(root, text="This is Header")
mLabel.pack
mLabel.mainloop()
```

But I got an exception saying

```
ImportError: No module named '_tkinter', please install the python3-tk package
```

And I tried to install the python3-tk like this

```
sudo apt-get install python3-tk
```

And I was raised with the exceptions like below
[image]

**Please guide me through What I am missing**

Comment: You could try asking that on https://askubuntu.com/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe in your case, just running `apt-get update` before `apt-get install python3-tk` may be enough.

I had this problem while running it inside a Dockerfile. I had in my Dockerfile:

```
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install python3-tk -y
```

And it was failing with the same message as yours.
I realised that if I ran both lines outside of Docker, they worked fine, and that the `apt-get update` was using cache while running the `docker-compose build`.
When I run `docker-compose build --no-cache`, it worked.